# Why do my event.clientX return undefined?

Tags: javascript, coordinates

I am working on a set of pop-up div's, that will appear if the user attempts to drag something, that has already been dragged.

**Question**: Why doesn't the console return coordinates?

**Code**:

```
        startDragEventHandler: function (event) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains('alreadyUsed')) {
            var x_pos = event.clientX
            var y_pos = event.clientY

            var d = document.getElementById('o_tip');
            d.style.display = "block";
            d.style.position = "absolute";

            // This should set the position in CSS according to X & Y
            d.style.left = x_pos +'px';
            d.style.top = y_pos +'px';

            // Just to debug in dev tools' console
            console.log("x_pos: ", x_pos);
            console.log("y_pos: ", y_pos);
        };
```

It's called by:

```
     events: {
        "mousedown .o_slide": "startDragEventHandler",
        "touchstart .o_slide": "startDragEventHandler",
        "MSPointerDown .o_slide": "startDragEventHandler",
```

My console in Chrome dev.tools will **return**:

```
x_pos:  undefined
y_pos:  undefined
```

*OBS: I know, that if it worked, it will give me coordinates relative to the element, not relative to the whole page - I am simply not finished implementing [this](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/getting_mouse_click_position.htm) solution.*

Comment: How is `startDragEventHandler` called ?

Comment: I've included the events, thanks

Comment: In case of `touchstart` it's normal : you need to grab the particular `.touches` that you want to read. For `mousedown` that's weird, are you sure that the `target`is the one you expect and not one of its decendants? For the other one, I don't know it...

Comment: Well, it does trigger and evaluate the function - I know because I am getting the console.log at the right time and place.

Comment: x_pos:  undefined
y_pos:  undefined

Comment: weird... What does `console.log(event)` returns? What if you rename `event` with `evt`  everywhere (don't forget `function (event)` => `function (evt)`) Can you provide an [MCVE]?

Comment: Which html element `o_slide` is ?

Comment: `o_slide` is the draggable div. It's a thumbnail, when dragged if 'alreadyUsed', the event fires. `o_tip` is the div meant to pop up with the clicked coordinates.